# Traefik - Get the User IP

Tags: apache, docker, proxy, docker-compose, traefik

I have an Apache server that is behind Traefik.
Now I want to get the user's IP, but I only get the container's internal IP.

I control all containers via a docker-compose file

docker-compose.yml:

```
app:
  image: traefik:1.7.20-alpine
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "MyIP:80:80"
    - "MyIP:443:443"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
    - ./acme.json:/acme.json
  networks:
    - webserver

Apache-Server:
  build: ./apache/
  networks:
    - webserver
  labels:
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:MyWebsite.tld"
    - "traefik.enable=true"
  links:
    - mysql:db
  volumes:
    - ./apache/public/:/var/www/html/:rw
  restart: always
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get install libpng-dev -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

How can I pass the real user IP?